# uncheck other checkbox in jsf 2 in p:datatable

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I am using dataTableSelectOneRadio to uncehck other checked box and enable single selection. it was working fine in h:datatable , when I migrated to p:datatable it started allowing  one selection in each page, but I want only one selection selection for complete rows.

```
<p:datatable var="countryLangObj" value="#{countryBean.countryLanguageList}" rows="5" paginator="true">
   <p:column  headerText="Default" styleClass="default">
      <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="checkBox" value="#{countryLangObj.isDefaultLanguage}" onclick="dataTableSelectOneRadio(this);" />
   </p:column>
</p:datatable>

function dataTableSelectOneRadio(radio) {
     var id = radio.name.substring(radio.name.lastIndexOf(':'));
     var el = radio.form.elements;
     for (var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
         if (el[i].name.substring(el[i].name.lastIndexOf(':')) == id) {
             el[i].checked = false;
         }
     }
     radio.checked = true;
}
```

Comment: dataTableSelectOneRadio is a javascript method ? If yes, you should provide the code

Comment: provided javascript method ..

Comment: Why don't you just use `<p:dataTable selectionMode="single">`?